# Shows Result Jquery Autocomplete On Click?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have some problem to show result of autocomplete by clicking the textbox.
In my script the autocomplete run when I have completed type a words and when I want to show result again I must **press the down arrows**. How can I show the result again with just **clicking the textbox and highlighting the word**? I user ._renderItem function to show result.

This is my code :

```
$("#NO_CONT" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 8,
            max : 10,
            scroll: true ,
            width: 410,
            height: 70,
            matchContains: true,
            autoFill: false,
            search  : function(){$(this).addClass('working');},
            open    : function(){$(this).removeClass('working');}, 
            //source: "{$HOME}{$APPID}.auto/container",
            source: function( request, response ) {
                var term = request.term;
                if ( term in cache ) {
                    response( cache[ term ] );
                    return;
                }
                $.getJSON( "{$HOME}{$APPID}.auto/container", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                    cache[ term ] = data;
                    response( data );
                });
            },
            focus: function( event, ui ) {              
                $("#NO_CONT").val( ui.item.NO_CONTAINER );              
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#NO_CONT").val( ui.item.NO_CONTAINER );
                $("#NO_CONT2").val( ui.item.NO_CONTAINER );


                return false;
            }
        })
        .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li style='text-align:left'></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a style='text-align:left;font-size:16px;'>" + item.NO_CONTAINER + "<br/> "+item.SIZE_+" "+item.TYPE_+" | ["+item.NM_KAPAL+"] ["+item.VOYAGE_IN+"]</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `minChars:0` property

```
$("#NO_CONT" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 8,
            max : 10,
            scroll: true ,
            width: 410,
            height: 70,
            minChars:0,
            ................
```

custom output sample:

```
$("#imageSearch").autocomplete("images.php", {
    width: 320,
    max: 4,
    highlight: false,
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 300,
    formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
        return "<img src='images/" + value + "'/> " + value.split(".")[0];
    },
    formatResult: function(data, value) {
        return value.split(".")[0];
    }
});
```

Others example http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/

Answer (score 0):

[This is a perfect JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LesignButure/EVsye/) of what you want to do I believe.

It is also well documented, so I don't think I should add extra explanation. However, I must show a piece of code otherwise StackOverflow won't let me post this link.

```
$.extend($.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
```